# How to create and style div on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, element

I am attempting to use the onclick on the button to call the function complete which should create a div with the below mentioned attributes. However, when I tried to run it, I saw no output display. I have tried a bunch of things but am currently unsure. Any help would be much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <button id ="button1" type="button" onclick="complete()">Run</button>
    <script>
        function complete(){
            var x= Math.floor(Math.random()*501)
            var y=Math.floor(Math.random()*501)
            var divx = document.createElement("div");
            divx.style.position = "fixed";
            divx.style.bottom = (150+x).toString();
            divx.style.right = (900+y).toString();
            divx.style.background="green";
            divx.style.width = "10px";
            divx.style.height = "10px";
            divx.style.border = "1px solid #000";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(div);` should probably be `document.body.appendChild(divx);`

Comment: For your other issue, append px to the strings. It's css-style, flat numbers do not mean anything without their unit. For example: `divx.style.bottom = (150+x).toString() + "px"`;

Comment: @mmm what make you think that this post should be in Server Fault?

Comment: @Abdulla what make you think that this post should be in Server Fault?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, you're missing just to add `x` after `div` in :

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Should be :

```
document.body.appendChild(divx);
```

Because variable `div` is not defined, also you should put your code inside `<body>` tag for the valid HTML code.

Hope this helps.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id ="button1" type="button" onclick="complete()">Run</button>
    <script>
      function complete(){
        var x= Math.floor(Math.random()*501)
        var y=Math.floor(Math.random()*501)
        var divx = document.createElement("div");
        divx.style.position = "fixed";
        divx.style.bottom = (150+x).toString();
        divx.style.right = (900+y).toString();
        divx.style.background="green";
        divx.style.width = "10px";
        divx.style.height = "10px";
        divx.style.border = "1px solid #000";
        document.body.appendChild(divx);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line `document.body.appendChild(div);` uses an undefined variable `div`, you named your div `xdiv` instead, so use that as parameter.

Remember that most browsers support a console, usually accessible through `F12`, which shows error messages triggered by JavaScript. In your case it shows:

```
test.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: div is not defined
```

It's a great idea to check that error log when something misbehaves, often it tells exactly what's wrong including the line number.

---

You also have to append the unit as a string when setting the two offsets (`bottom` and `right`), probably `px`. For example:

```
divx.style.bottom = (150+x).toString() + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The error :

`document.body.appendChild(div);` should be `document.body.appendChild(divx);`

#### Suggestion :

While not incorrect, you shouldn't use `onclick="complete()"` in your HTML. It's much better to attach an event listener using [`addEventListener("click", complete, false)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in your JS code instead.

#### Improved code :

```js
function complete(){
    var x= Math.floor(Math.random()*501)
    var y=Math.floor(Math.random()*501)
    var divx = document.createElement("div");
    divx.style.position = "fixed";
    divx.style.bottom = (150+x).toString();
    divx.style.right = (900+y).toString();
    divx.style.background="green";
    divx.style.width = "10px";
    divx.style.height = "10px";
    divx.style.border = "1px solid #000";
    document.body.appendChild(divx);
}

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener("click", complete, false);
```

```html
<button id ="button1" type="button">Run</button>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sgkpfxe4/))

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.appendChild(div);` **should be** `document.body.appendChild(divx);` Because `div` is undefined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button id="button1" type="button" onclick="complete()">Run</button>
  <script>
    function complete() {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501)
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501)
      var divx = document.createElement("div");
      divx.style.position = "fixed";
      divx.style.bottom = (150 + x).toString();
      divx.style.right = (900 + y).toString();
      divx.style.background = "green";
      divx.style.width = "10px";
      divx.style.height = "10px";
      divx.style.border = "1px solid #000";
      document.body.appendChild(divx);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```